# Difference between 2 @Index and 1 @Index with multiple columns in hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, database-administration

What will be the difference in query performance regarding

```
@Table(name = "users", indexes = {
    @Index(columnList = "code", name = "code"),
    @Index(columnList = "current_city", name = "cbplayer_current_city_hidx")
})
```

vs.

```
@Table(name = "users", indexes = {
    @Index(columnList = "code, current_city", name = "both"),
})
```

Will both of these just create a b-tree for code and a b-tree for current city?  Or will the second one create some kind of b-tree involving both?

The first one seems more flexible where I can query on code and later query on code/current_city later as my system evolves without needing to do DBA work(KISS until need even better performance).

I am really just curious on the difference here.

Comment: Being curious, involves doing "DBA work", maybe you should "KISS until need even better performance" ?   (or do some research yourself....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what that generates, use the commandline tool `mysql` and use the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` command.

When is the composite `INDEX(a,bb)` useful?  When are separate `INDEX(a), INDEX(bb)` useful?  Some examples

```
WHERE a = 'xyz'               -- INDEX(a) or INDEX(a,bb)
WHERE a = 'xyz' AND bb = 123  -- INDEX(a,bb) or INDEX(bb,a); others are less good
WHERE a = 'xyz' AND bb >= 123 -- INDEX(a,bb); others are less good
WHERE a >= 'xyz' AND bb = 123 -- INDEX(bb,a) is best
WHERE bb = 123                -- INDEX(bb) or INDEX(bb,a)
```

That is, the optimal index depends on what the important queries are.

On the other hand, if the table has only a hundred rows, you are unlikely to notice any performance issues if you don't have any indexes.

Another discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: what if I INDEX(a) and INDEX(b) instead of INDEX(a, b) or is this the same @Rick James?  Is this creating two b-trees or one -> INDEX(a, b)?

Comment: @DeanHiller - I did some rewriting and added a link.

Comment: great answer @Rick James though in my example just for clarity.  both examples 'I think are INDEX(a, bb), are they not?  The columnList in the second one lists two.  I will try to get some time to get one of my developers to run it and see the difference.

Comment: @DeanHiller - I don't know hibernate (nor the other hundred packages that _try_ to hide MySQL from the user), but I would guess that your two snippets of code correspond to `INDEX(a), INDEX(bb)` and `INDEX(a, bb)`, respectively.